# Linear Fit to Planet Positions

Tags: javascript, python

An astounding alignment occurs 2048/5/28 with the inner 5 planets
having heliocentric longitudes (in degrees):
  248.229, 66.631, 246.967, 249.605, 67.684.

The planets are at most 0.875 degrees from the line (through Sol)
with slope 67.823 degrees.  In this case, the method sought (PA) would give:
   PA(248.229, 66.631, 246.967, 249.605, 67.684) = (67.823, 0.875)

I have tried two simple algorithms which both fail on the case:
   2003/9/9:  340.256, 180.320, 346.156, 342.316, 150.285

One method gives slope=127.867, deviation=51.019 and the other 271.867, 85.251.
I think a correct method would give s=163.466, d=7.515.

The main problem is that planets on opposite sides of Sol can be (nearly) on the same line.

Python or javascript appreciated.
Yay I figured out how to edit! Or not.

```
def score3(wList):
  wSize = len(wList)
  #print wList

  first = wList[0]
  d1 = first - 90.0
  if d1 < 0.0:    d1 += 360.0
  d2 = first + 90.0
  if d2 > 360.0:  d1 -= 360.0
  if d1 > d2:   d1,d2 = d2,d1

  sum = 0.0
  for wx in range(0,wSize):
    curr = wList[wx]
    if (curr > d1) and (curr < d2):
      new = curr
    else:
      new = (curr + 180.0) % 360.0
      wList[wx] = new
    sum += new
    #print '%7.3f --> %7.3f' % (curr, new)
  avg = sum / wSize
  #print avg, wList

  score = 0.0
  for wx in range(0,wSize):
    curr = wList[wx]
    diff = curr - avg
    if diff < 0:   diff = - diff
    score += diff
  score /= wSize

  return avg, score
```

Comment: Math questions should go to mathoverflow.net.

Comment: Post what you've tried, then you can get critiques on the method(s)

Comment: Maybe you should show your algorithms that fail then someone may be able to point out where the problem lies.

Comment: Um...if you are able to calculate the expected value by hand, why can't you use the same method in code?

Comment: LOL, it has been 40 years since I have had to turn in homework.
Code is too long for box.  I try to separate two ends of line by picking an element and adding to list anything within -90 and +90 of that first choice.  Then I add 180 to everything not in list to put the two groups together.  Answer is their average and does not work.

Comment: Don't use comments for posting code, edit the question.

Comment: Thank you for code, it is much shorter than mine but like my first try gives avg= 85.042, spread= 84.722.  Strange, this should be simple.

Comment: Comments to answer should go on the answers...

Answer (score 0):

Dumb as dirt method didn't work for reasons that should have been obvious: your data can be pathological for any choice of half-plane to map to. I'm going to recommend a [least squares approach](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html), but you do need to deal with the radial ambiguity.

That means the function that you are looking to minimize is:

```
\sum (forceAngleIntoQuandrantI(a_i - A))^2
```

or something equivalent. That is, the planet can never lie more than 90 degrees from the proposed line.

Now, if you use a forcing routine like I showed initially (you can still find that in the edit history for this answer), the problem is no longer analytical and you'll have to use an iterative approach (see [Bisection Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) for a simple approach). Or you can note that sin^2(theta) is monotonically increasing in quadrants I,IV and symmetric about the +- 90 degree line and minimize

```
\sum sin^4(a_i - A)
```

without clipping using the analytical methods described in the MathWorld link (or [look at wikipdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) if you prefer).